# What exactly is the definition of $P = (S, |)$ in a partially ordered set?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, set-theory

[The problem I have difficulty with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gosAQ.png)

I get that the set $S$ can be simplified into $S =$ {20, 25, 32, 40, 50, 64, 80, 100}
However, I don't exactly what the question is trying to say for $P = (S, |)$, and the 'minimal' and 'maximal' elements of $P$.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: The relation $\mid$ is a partial order on your set. For intuition: you can imagine that a number $x$ is treated as "smaller" than number $y$ iff $x$ divides $y$. Now, the "minimal" elements are *those that don't have another smaller element*, and the "maximal" elements are *those that don't have another larger element* in the set. For example, $50$ is neither minimal (as there is "smaller" number $25$ in the set: $25\mid 50$) nor maximal (as there is "larger" number $100$ in the set: $50\mid 100$).